# Field.class.getDeclaredFields() is returning an empty array

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, jvm

When trying to get the `modifiers` field from the `Field` class reflectively, I get a `NoSuchFieldException`. And when printing out a list of the declared fields I get an empty array.

```
 try {
        modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
 } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e + Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(Field.class.getDeclaredFields()).map(Field::getName).toArray()));
 }
```

Output: `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers[]`

Tried updating Java, Tried doing it in Kotlin. To no avail.

Comment: If you need the value of the `modifiers` field, use its public accessor: `getModifiers()`. If you want to change the modifiers, use a java agent to change the bytecode before it is loaded.